# Is there a way to merge 2 querysets in Django and order them by a their repecting field?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a twitter clone and this is my user and tweet Model(some irrelevant fields have been removed).

```
class TwitterUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    Bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    ProfilePicture = models.ImageField(upload_to="Twitter", default="../static/twitter/images/default_profile.png")
    CreateDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    TweetBody = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=False)
    TweetDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Owner= models.ForeignKey(to=TwitterUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="Owner")
    RetweetedBy= models.ManyToManyField(to=TwitterUser,related_name="Retweeted",blank=True,through="RetweetIntermediate")
```

and this the table that my many to many relationship for retweet is using.

```
class RetweetIntermediate(models.Model):
    twitteruser=models.ForeignKey(TwitterUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet=models.ForeignKey(Tweet,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    retweetDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

In profile view all the tweets and retweets should be shown ordered by date
what I'm doing right now (and it is working fine) is this:

```
def keymaker(a):
    return a.TweetDate
def ProfileView(request):
    tweets= list(Tweet.objects.filter(Owner=user.user_id,IsReplyToTweet__isnull=True).order_by("-TweetDate"))
    retweets = list(user.Retweeted.all().order_by("-id"))
    retweetInter=RetweetIntermediate.objects.all().order_by("-tweet_id")
    for i , j in zip(retweets,retweetInter):
        i.TweetDate=j.retweetDate
    tweets=(tweets+retweets)
    tweets.sort(key=keymaker,reverse=True)
```

I retrieve all the tweets ordered by date. then I retrieve all of retweets and make a list out of them and change the data of tweet to the date saved in intermediate table
and merge both lists and sort them by date.
**I want to know is there a better way or more standard way to do this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this statement i.TweetDate=j.retweetDate is supposed to do?

Comment: every tweet has a date.(when user tweets it)
if you retweet a tweet date of that retweet is saved in RetweetIntermediate.
what i.TweetDate=j.retweetDate is doing :
"i" is the tweet that you retweeted that has the date when it was originally tweeted.
"j" is the query in RetweetIntermediate that has the Retweet date.
so when you order all the tweets (tweet that you posted and tweets of other people that you retweeted are shown in a right order of time
if I dont do that your tweets and retweets are show based on the time that they were tweeted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) together with [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

```py
from django.db.models import F

tweets_qs = Tweet.objects\
  .filter(Owner=user, IsReplyToTweet__isnull=True)\
  .annotate(date=F('TweetDate'))

retweets_qs = Tweet.objects\
  .filter(retweetintermediate__twitteruser=user)\
  .annotate(date=F('retweetintermediate__retweetDate'))

timeline_qs = tweets_qs.union(retweets_qs).order_by('-date')
```

Notice that both querysets have `Tweet` objects.

Edit: Sorry for not understanding the question correctly the first time.

Comment: actually I know about unions but my problem is not with the merging 2 querysets.
if i do what you said this scenario will happen (time order)
user A tweets.
user B tweets.
user B retweets user A tweet.
in User B profile you see (older to newer)
user A tweet then user B tweet
but User B retweeted User A tweet recently so it should be shown higher.
I hope that clarified this

Comment: So basically I'm sorting it by the date of the tweet but if it's a retweet, it should be sorted by the retweet date. Did I understand it correctly, now?

Comment: yes thats it. I did it by making a list an doing this  {for i , j in zip(retweets,retweetInter):i.TweetDate=j.retweetDate} 
but i want to know if there is a better way

Comment: Thanks that did it.